# OnMessage(WebSocket) not working in Glassfish, Java 8

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish

I am having trouble with running my Java EE application. I have the folloving code for server edpoint:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;



@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint(
        value = "/model" 
)
public class ModelWebSocket {


    private final ModelHandle model = new ModelHandle();   

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {

    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        /// put model back to pool, log erros
    }


    // This code never calls,
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {

        //TODO: Add decoders/encoders to annotations
        try {       
            ModelInputData inputData = new ModelInputDataDecoder().decode(message);         
            double input = inputData.getInput();
            double timespan = inputData.getTimespan();

            model.setInput(input);

            ModelProcessData process = model.getOuptput(timespan);

            try {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(
                        new ModelProcessDataEncoder().encode(process)
                );
            } catch (IOException | EncodeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ModelWebSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (DecodeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ModelWebSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

And the following stub for a client stub in javascript:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a test
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- insert the main script here -->

        <script type ="text/javascript">

            //copied from https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets
            var socket = new WebSocket(
                    "ws://localhost:8080/SimulatorWeb/model"
                    );

            socket.onopen = function () {
                alert("Connection OK");
            };

            socket.onclose = function (event) {
                if (event.wasClean) {
                    alert('Connection closed');
                } else {
                    alert('Connection interrupted'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
                }
                alert('Code: ' + event.code + ' redason: ' + event.reason);
            };

            socket.onmessage = function (event) {
                alert("Data accepted " + event.data);
            };

            socket.onerror = function (error) {
                alert("Error " + error.message);
            };



            function send(){ 
              socket.send("dummy");
            }
        </script>

        <button type="button" onclick="send();" >Send</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Client seem to send message, but OnMessage is never intercepted.
I have the following warn's when I start Glassfish 4.1.1:

- *WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private
  org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
  ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated
  types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a
  generic type with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
  [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public
  org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
  ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated
  types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a
  generic type with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
  [BackedAnnotatedMethod]
  org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
  ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all
  annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations
  or a generic type with bounds.*

I have spent I lot of time debugging, but I'm still not able to find the issue... I use Java 8 SDK and NetBeans IDE.

(In the code I use no decoders/encoders, because I thought that they were the issue and removed them from ServerEnpoint)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the issue with Glassfish is... I swithed to Tomcat and added manually to WEB_INF/lib all external libraries I needed (javax.json in my case). Tomcat seems to give no warnings to the original code and everything works just fine.